# Magento 2: Get Payment Information in checkout_submit_all_after event observer

Tags: event-observer, payment, magento2.1.6

I have need to get Payment information in **checkout_submit_all_after** event observer.

File path: **magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events/xml**

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="order_create_all_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
```

File path: **magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderObserver.php**

```
class OrderObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
    }
}
```

I have try to print order object through the getdata but not get payment information.

Any help will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event ?

Comment: @Pawan thanks I will try  with checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event

Comment: Sure, let me know if worked.